# Time to reach max Wi-Fi performance after acquiring WifiLock

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

Consider the case: Wi-Fi is connected and the application is about to perform a network-intense operation (e.g. VoIP call). To guarantee link quality during the operation I acquire `WifiLock` with flag `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF`. Lock is released when operation completes.

Does this immediately brings Wi-Fi to full performance or there is a delay? Should I wait for some interval of time before performing the operation?